# grep or sed to find a integer value above a given amount?

Tags: grep, sed

This is in reference to another question: [How do I use robocopy to list all files over a certain size recursively?](https://serverfault.com/questions/307573/how-do-i-use-robocopy-to-list-all-files-over-a-certain-size-recursively/307614)

I would like to parse output of a command (or cat a log file) and find a string value, convert it to an integer and then see if that integer value is greater than a given integer.

For instance, given the line:

```
      *EXTRA File          78223    C:\_Google.Enterprise.Contract.2010-06-01.pdf
```

I'd like to compare '78223' to '10485760'.  Is this possible with grep or sed?

Thanks!

Comment: You probably awk, or a scripting language for numerical comparisons.

Comment: Tho should have been moved to the UNIX stackexchange.

Comment: @JimB : possibly, but Questions  [older than 60 days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work) can't be migrated.

Comment: It's a Windows question... just gaze upon the path.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `awk` as follows:

```
$ echo '*EXTRA File     78223    C:\foo.pdf' | awk '$3 > 1048576 {print $0;}'
$ echo '*EXTRA File     78223    C:\foo.pdf' | awk '$3 > 40000 {print $0;}'
*EXTRA File     78223    C:\foo.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks.  Not familiar with awk.  It looks to be very handy.

Answer (score 4):

Also - if you're using a Unix-like userland (like UnxUtils or Cygwin, if you're on Windows), you can use `find` with the `-size` parameter to get your file list directly, and then pipe to xargs and do whatever you're trying to do with the selected files.

The general answer to your question (interesting comparisons and other operations) is indeed awk or bash (with bc) or perl - but the specific scenario lends itself to `find`.

Comment: Bash can natively perform integer math, check out http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression

Comment: find can also -exec rather than piping to xargs.  If xargs-like "all arguments in one command" style is preferred, terminate with + rather than ;  Check out http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind#Actions_in_bulk:_xargs.2C_-print0_and_-exec_.2B- :)

Answer (score 2):

In pure Bash:

```
while read -r _ _ size _; do ((size > 10485760)) && echo "hit"; done < foo.log
```

Comment: This can be easily modified to report any field(s) or the entire line if there is a match, and/or custom-define the comparison integer at runtime.  If you want that, just LMK.

Answer (score 0):

Perl can be used similarly to awk:

`echo '*EXTRA File  78223  C:\foo.pdf' | perl -ane 'print if $F[2] > 40000'`